# Batch file to run xcopy without overwriting existing files

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy

I need my program to run:

```
xcopy s:\* z:\ /E
```

When xcopy runs, it will prompt if a file needs to be overwritten, so I want the batch file to answer no in all cases to the prompt.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Just bumped into this. `/D` worked for me. You don't have to specify the date, in which case it means *any* existing file.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/191209/945456

Answer (score 41):

I've been using the following flags for years. It seems to accomplish all the behaviors you describe in the question.

`xcopy s:\ z:\ /S /Y /D`

S will copy all subfolders and files within them
Y prevents any overwrite prompts
D essentially copies anything newer than what is already in the destination

Comment: /y is to allow xcopy to overwrite the file without prompting.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/240268

Comment: Worked beautifully for me!

Answer (score 35):

I almost overlooked this in the switches myself.  I was aided by an Experts Exchange article.

Here is the switch of significance:

/D:m-d-y     Copies files changed on or after the specified date.
             If no date is given, copies only those files whose
             source time is newer than the destination time.

The "If no date is given" portion is of particular importance.  This doesn't exactly answer the "without the overwriting existing files" question, but it does answer it if the existing file's time stamp of the source file is not newer than the destination file.

Close enough for government work.

Answer (score 8):

xcopy cannot be configured to SKIP existing files, so you should copy using "robocopy".

Comment: `xcopy /D` does not help if you need to actually use a date limitation.

Comment: And how do you use `robocopy` to achieve this?

Comment: From  XCOPY /?
  /D
If no date is given, copies only those files whose source time is newer than the destination time.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
echo n|xcopy s:\* z:\ /E
```

Comment: that works for a single file.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid question y/n/all you can simulate "type in" using echo command as:
echo n|xcopy blabla...
But it´s not correct because any different question will be answer "n" too.

Better choice in cmd to replace xcopy is:
robocopy source: destination: /e [/zb]

In graphical mode, there is a app called "Teracopy" (use google to find it) that override windows explorer copy with several options (pause, ignore[all], overwrite[all], minimize,...) that I would like to recommend.

Comment: How the `/zb` option help us with skipping existing files?

Answer (score 0):

> Windows Command Interpreter:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /b /s "source"') do (echo n | xcopy "%i" "destination"  [switches] /-y)
```

---

> Windows Batch:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s "source"') do (echo n | xcopy "%%i" "destination"  [switches] /-y)
```

**Please remember to make sure it prompts you before starting to copy/overwrite any files.**

Comment: I would like to thank [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246665/chris) for providing the hilarious yet [useful solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191209/how-to-say-no-to-all-do-you-want-to-overwrite-prompts-in-a-batch-file-copy#2030111) for me. I had been using that better solution for 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

```
(FOR /f %M IN ('dir /s s:\') DO @echo n)|xcopy s:\ z:\ /S /Y /D
```

this will answer N for every file...