# How do I copy a folder and all subfolders and files in .NET?

Tags: .net, file, copy, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to copy the entire contents of a directory in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744/best-way-to-copy-the-entire-contents-of-a-directory-in-c-sharp)

I'd like to copy folder with all its subfolders and file from one location to another in .NET. What's the best way to do this?

I see the Copy method on the System.IO.File class, but was wondering whether there was an easier, better, or faster way than to crawl the directory tree.

Comment: http://xneuron.wordpress.com/2007/04/12/copy-directory-and-its-content-to-another-directory-in-c/ might be helpful to you; it shows a simple recursive method

Comment: I look forward to when I need to do operations on the file system because I have a legitimate excuse to use recursion!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Well, there's the VisualBasic.dll implementation that Steve references, and here's something that I've used.

```
private static void CopyDirectory(string sourcePath, string destPath)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(destPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destPath);
    }

    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath))
    {
        string dest = Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(file));
        File.Copy(file, dest);
    }

    foreach (string folder in Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath))
    {
        string dest = Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(folder));
        CopyDirectory(folder, dest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Michal Talaga references the following in his [post](http://vaultofthoughts.net/DirectoryCopyInNET.aspx):

- Microsoft's explanation about why there shouldn't be a Directory.Copy() operation in .NET.
- An implementation of CopyDirectory() from the Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll assembly.

However, a recursive implementation based on `File.Copy()` and `Directory.CreateDirectory()` should suffice for the most basic of needs.

Comment: That's an interesting link. I'm not sure Microsoft's arguments hold much water. But it does explain why the functionality is missing.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't get anything better... perhaps use `Process.Start` to fire up `robocopy.exe`?

Comment: Robocopy doesn't parse quotes properly when run with Process.Start, so your source/destination paths must not contain spaces. If they do, you have to use the 8dot3 filename. The only time Robocopy seems to accept quotes properly is from a command line or BAT file.

Comment: @Brain2000 you can always use short paths if spaces are an issue