# Copy Sub directories to directory

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, directory, copy

Referencing this question/code:

[How do I copy a folder and all subfolders and files in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066674/how-do-i-copy-a-folder-and-all-subfolders-and-files-in-net)

I'm trying to copy a buntch of sub directories to a different directory.  I'm wanting to update this code:

```
Dim fso As System.Object = New System.Object
    fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    fso.copyfolder(sour, dest)
```

However I'm getting this error:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
>   path 'C:\Temp\Summer2011\Newfolder\Copy of New Text Document.txt'. at
>   System.IO._E_Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String
>   destFileName, Boolean overwrite) at System.IO.File.Copy(String
>   sourceFileName, String destFileName)...etc

With this .NET version

```
 Public Overrides Sub OnClick()

            Dim sour As String = "C:\Temp243"
            Dim dest As String = "C:\Temp\Summer2011\"

            CopyDirectory(sour, dest)

    End Sub



    Private Sub CopyDirectory(ByVal SourcePath As String, ByVal DestPath As String)

                     If Directory.Exists(DestPath) Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(DestPath)
            End If

            For Each File As String In Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath)
                Dim dest As String = IO.Path.Combine(DestPath, IO.Path.GetFileName(File))
                IO.File.Copy(File, dest) '<<<ERROR HERE

            Next

            For Each folder As String In Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath)
                Dim dd As String = IO.Path.Combine(DestPath, IO.Path.GetFileName(folder))
                CopyDirectory(folder, dd)
            Next

    End Sub
```

Is there a easier way of doing this with less lines of code like the fso As System.Object version?  Also, I have System.IO imported however File.Copy and Directory.GetFiles are not colored blue, could this be the issue?  I have the System loaded as a reference.

Thank you!

Comment: Does that directory path exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127956.aspx) method.

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(sourceDirectory, destinationDirectory)
```

Hope this helps.