# how do I copy a folder to a USB? C#

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, copy, directory

I'm working on a project that will automatically update my USB with some files from my computer.

The program works on start up and monitors for any USB or CD that is plugged into the computer. My program is to then copy some folders and its files to the USB. I am having trouble copying the folders into the USB and would appreciate some help, thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;




namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

 // this section starts the timer so it can moniter when a USB or CD is inserted into
 // the computer.    
//==================================================================================
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Interval = 100;
            timer1.Start();

            WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
//===================================================================================            
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

 // this section checks to see if there is a drive type of USB and CDs.          

            foreach(DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
            {
                if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
                {
// this part is supposed to copy a folder from the PC and paste it to the USB
//==============================================================================                    

//==============================================================================                   
                }

                if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.CDRom)
                {
// same thing but for CDs.
//==============================================================================

//==============================================================================
                }
            }


        }
// this section opens a folderbrowserdialog that the users can use to access their folders 
//and put them into a listbox so when a USB or CD is inserted it will copy those files into
// the storage devices.
//==============================================================================
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
//==============================================================================
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: What kind of problem? Could you show your code?

Comment: You will have to create the folder structure in the destination and then copy the files . see the link for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066674/how-do-i-copy-a-folder-and-all-subfolders-and-files-in-net?rq=1

Comment: I loaded my code with some comments, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914.aspx) is how it can be done:

```
private static void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
    DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

    if (!dir.Exists)
    {
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
            "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
            + sourceDirName);
    }

    if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
    }

    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
        file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
    }

    if (copySubDirs)
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
        {
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
            DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use File.Copy and use the USB drive letter for the destination.  For example:

```
string sourceDir = @"c:\current";
string backupDir = @"f:\archives\2008";

try
{
    string[] picList = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.jpg");
    string[] txtList = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.txt");

    // Copy picture files. 
    foreach (string f in picList)
    {
        // Remove path from the file name. 
        string fName = f.Substring(sourceDir.Length + 1);

        // Use the Path.Combine method to safely append the file name to the path. 
        // Will overwrite if the destination file already exists.
        File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourceDir, fName), Path.Combine(backupDir, fName), true);
    }

    // Copy text files. 
    foreach (string f in txtList)
    {

        // Remove path from the file name. 
        string fName = f.Substring(sourceDir.Length + 1);

        try
        {
            // Will not overwrite if the destination file already exists.
            File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourceDir, fName), Path.Combine(backupDir, fName));
        }

        // Catch exception if the file was already copied. 
        catch (IOException copyError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(copyError.Message);
        }
    }

    // Delete source files that were copied. 
    foreach (string f in txtList)
    {
        File.Delete(f);
    }
    foreach (string f in picList)
    {
        File.Delete(f);
    }
}

catch (DirectoryNotFoundException dirNotFound)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dirNotFound.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please refer to MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914.aspx