# copy whole shared directory from network

Tags: c#, .net, copy

I am trying to copy whole directory tree from server's shared  folder to my local machine, I found [Best way to copy the entire contents of a directory in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744/best-way-to-copy-the-entire-contents-of-a-directory-in-c) post and decide to use that but as I guess DirectoryInfo doesn't support network shares, how can I change this code to work with network shares as a source?

```
public static void CopyFilesRecursively(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target) {
    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in source.GetDirectories())
        CopyFilesRecursively(dir, target.CreateSubdirectory(dir.Name));
    foreach (FileInfo file in source.GetFiles())
        file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, file.Name));
}
```

**EDIT**
and the call is

```
CopyFilesRecursively(new DirectoryInfo ("\\192.168.0.11\Share"), new DirectoryInfo ("D:\Projects\"));
```

and getting error message

```
Could not find a part of the path 'D:\192.168.0.11\Share'.
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about escaping the strings?

```
CopyFilesRecursively(
    new DirectoryInfo(@"\\192.168.0.11\Share"),
    new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Projects\"));
```

MSDN says that [DirectoryInfo can handle UNC paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Also, try:

```
DirectoryInfo di=new DirectoryInfo(@"\\<server>\<share>");
```

Specific point being the @ symbol; this works on my local network.

Answer (score 0):

can you pass into the function the unc pathing of the folder instead?  `\\servername\physical path to folder`?

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't support the UNC path, you could map the network share to a drive letter. Not terribly portable if you need to do this for a user specified share; but would work if you only need to focus on one share.

on XP: My Computer -> Tools -> Map Network Drive