# Connecting / Copying from network drive

Tags: c#, network-programming

Not totally sure how to approach this. I've researched a bit but I've come up short. Trying to connect to the network drives at work and copy out the newest folder (updates to a project) For me, the dir starts as \ but when i add that to a string variable it won't connect and won't display when i attempt to check it. is there a process to this?

This is what i have. And it has to be wrong in someway.

```
string updir = @"\\NetworkDrive\updates\xxxxx";

public void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
    {

        try
        {
            //check if the target directory exists
            if (Directory.Exists(target.FullName) == false)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);
            }

            //copy all the files into the new directory

            foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
            {
                fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.ToString(), fi.Name), true);
            }


            //copy all the sub directories using recursion

            foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceDir in source.GetDirectories())
            {
                DirectoryInfo nextTargetDir = target.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceDir.Name);
                CopyAll(diSourceDir, nextTargetDir);
            }
            //success here
            copyall = true;    
        }

        catch (IOException ie)
        {
            //handle it here
            copyall = false;
        }
    }
```

i've been using that to copy. And it works well.

```
DateTime lastHigh = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
        string highDir;
        foreach (string subdir in Directory.GetDirectories(updir))
        {
            DirectoryInfo fi1 = new DirectoryInfo(subdir);
            DateTime created = fi1.LastWriteTime;

            if (created > lastHigh)
            {
                highDir = subdir;
                lastHigh = created;
            }
        }
```

and that to find the newest folder.

Comment: Could you show the code that you used?

Comment: ive updated my desc with what i used to attempt to access the drive.

Comment: This can't be *all* your code. Please post the whole copy method. There should be a `.Copy()` somewhere.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266330/copy-whole-shared-directory-from-network

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with something like this (specifying access rights for the network share ):

```
string updir = @"\\NetworkDrive\updates\somefile";

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(username, password);
WindowsImpersonationContext context = identity.Impersonate();

File.Copy(updir, @"C:\somefile", true);
```

Comment: This ended up being the basis for what I needed. Thank you

Comment: I can't get this to work. First of all the second parameter is defined as "type" and not password. Second of all this should be the same as WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() which still throws an UnauthorizedAccessException. How did you get this to work actually?