# c# mapping network drive, access network folder

Tags: c#, wcf, networking, passwords, directory

I have a problem.

I have to create a `Wcf` service with a method that receives a `string` and write a file, on a server, with the content of that string.

I have to put the file in the url \server123\inp
(when I paste that url in the file explorer, I insert username and password and I access the directory.

How can I do it in c#?

I would like to something like this:

```
  IWshNetwork_Class network = new IWshNetwork_Class();
        network.MapNetworkDrive("k:", @"\\server123\in", Type.Missing, "username",    "password");
```

And after

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("k:\\file.txt",string);
```

But I have an error on the typed password(but the password is CORRECT!!)

Thanks a lot

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43091/Connect-to-a-UNC-Path-with-Credentials


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981802/connecting-copying-from-network-drive-c-sharp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5433640/939250