# How to copy a file from network to local machine in wcf service hosted as Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services

I'm writing a WCF service which will be hosted as a [Managed Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). This service will be running to check for available updates on a shared network drive for an application installed on the local machine.

Could anybody please help me out in how to download the file from the network drive on to the local machine and then run it to install the updates. The Windows Service will be installed with full administrative rights and hence can install and update the application.

Comment: Is the update location in your control or external?

Comment: The location will be on the central server and the path will be always available from the database. So, it would be accessible.

Comment: What is exactly the problem? You do not know how to access the file from the WCF service? You do not know how to send the file? You do not know how to run the file?

Comment: Accesing a networks share isn't different than a local file. What is the problem?

Comment: I do not know how to download the file. After downloading it I can run it on my local machine. But the issue is with downloading the file and, if required, handling the user authentication while accessing it.

Comment: @L.B, I need to get around the user authentication problem as the shared file on the network drive may not be always accessible.

Comment: You can send the file in a `byte[]`. You just load it from the WCF service, convert it to `byte[]` and send it to the client. Google object to byte array, there a lot of examples

Comment: @dhrumilap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981802/connecting-copying-from-network-drive-c-sharp