# Strange line break character appearing in C# generated CSV

Tags: c#

I use a OleDb data reader to read a number of records, and then write them to a CSV. I then read from this CSV using `File.ReadAllLines`, then split on commas to get my data. The problem is some parts of the CSV include a character I can't display (shows up as a square), which appears to act as a line break - this line break corrupts the CSV, so I need to get rid of it.

I've tried replacing `Environment.NewLine` with something else (a blank space) when writing the CSV, and ditto with `/r` and `/n` but to no avail - the character isn't replaced. What other ways are there to remove these?

Comment: Instead of parsing the CSV in your code, it really is best to leverage a parser library that has already been developed to handle discrepancies in encodings and edge cases with separators. You'll find this question useful: [Are there any CSV readers/writer libraries in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941392/are-there-any-csv-readers-writer-libraries-in-c)

Comment: Post the details of that char, and the relevant code for input/output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I then read from this CSV using File.ReadAllLines, then split on commas to get my data.

[Stop rolling your own CSV parser](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Dont write CSV file's this way... as it won't work in every scenario.

Use OLD DB to do it for you.

http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2008/09/17/tip-export-to-csv-using-ado-net.aspx

Hope that helps.