# C# print multiple columns in different cells in EXCEL

Tags: c#, excel, windows-7, streamwriter

I am working on C# in Win 7.

I need to print to a .txt file by Streamwriter.

```
  StreamWriter outputfile              = new StreamWriter(MYPATH, true);
  outputfile.Write(String.Format(WIDTH_1 + Constants.WIDTH_1, item1 + " " + subitem + "(ave.)" , item2 + " "+ subitem + "(dev.)"));
```

Here, WIDTH_1 is "{0,30}", WIDTH_2 is "{1,30}". 
item2 and item1 are all strings. 
subitme is string.

When I open it in EXCEL 2012, all columns are in one cell.

I need to print each column in a distinct cell.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try adding a tab character (\t) between each column value.

Comment: @wdosanjos , no it does not work. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

1.Make sure the file you are outputting to is in CSV format (*.CSV)

2.Make sure you have commas between the different columns as follows:

`outputfile.Write(String.Concat(col1value, ",", col2value, ",", col3value));`

3.Consider using a specific CSV library, rather than rolling your own. Follow the advice 'don't roll your own'.

[Are there any CSV readers/writer libraries in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941392/are-there-any-csv-readers-writer-libraries-in-c)

Comment: the output file is .txt not .csv. Is this a problem ?