# Reading CSV line by line and filling .net objects

Tags: .net, linq, csv

I have a csv file that I need to read one line at a time and fill .net objects from it (first line header).
 Now, I know I can do it via 
`ReadLine`
and then assign the object properties but I was wondering if there's any shorter way of doing it. 
 I tried using LINQ but that reads all the lines at ones 
`File.ReadAllLines("C:\\....csv").Skip(1)...`
 Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: please refer this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941392/are-there-any-csv-readers-writer-libraries-in-c

Comment: Replace `ReadAllLines` with [`ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yep Ivan say it, use `ReadLines()`

for reading header and data in one access you can use the old school Enumerator:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var enumerator = File.ReadLines("foo.csv").GetEnumerator();

  enumerator.MoveNext();
  string headerLine = enumerator.Current; // null if file empty

  while (enumerator.MoveNext())
  {
    string dataLine = enumerator.Current;
  }
}
```

or after the headline you can convert the Enumerator to IEnumerable<> back:

```
static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(IEnumerator<T> enumerator)
{
  while (enumerator.MoveNext()) yield return enumerator.Current;
}
```

and replace the while loop with `var query = AsEnumerable(enumerator);`