# replace string between delimiters

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've been trying my luck with Regex but my understanding doesn't seem to be the best.

**Problem**
I have a .csv file given to me by a 3rd party. I cannot edit it but need to read the data into my application.

There are always 12 columns in the file. However, sometimes it will go like this:

> text, text ,text,"text with comma,"
>
> text, text, text, text....
>
> text, text, text,"text with comma,","text with comma again", text...

What I need to do this replace all the commas between the "" with a -.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [Are there any CSV readers/writer libraries in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1941392/669576)

Comment: Johnny - Did not see that post in my travels. I'll look into it, seems like it's what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might do the trick for you

```
foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(YourCSV, "\"([^\"]*)\""))
    if(match.ToString().Contains(","))
        YourCSV = YourCSV.Replace(match.ToString(), match.ToString().Replace(",", "-"));
```

Comment: Helped but still not quite working right. probably fault on my part with my question description. When there is a comma between the commas they can be anywhere within that part of the string.

Comment: then it is more easier. just change `",\"", "-\""` to `",", "-"` in the replace

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help :) Happy Coding