# Mass Rename of Folder based on a CSV file

Tags: c#, csv

I  have a `.csv` file that has 2 columns: `PRE` and `POST`. The `PRE` column contains the old folder names and the POST column has the corresponding new folder names. I have about 1000 folders to rename and would like to automate it.

PRE,POST

123,123AB

003,234

456,789

Are you guys able to give me something to start with or point me to the right direction?

Comment: Is the value for each row a path to a directory or just the name? How are you planning to find out the location of the folder? or the folders exist in the same location of the csv file?

Comment: @luis They're just the names. The folders exist in the same location of the csv file

Comment: Please post what have you tried. @idk already provided a naive solution. If you need something to start. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507498/reading-csv-files-using-c-sharp) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941392/are-there-any-csv-readers-writer-libraries-in-c) posts if you need other ideas.

Comment: FYI: [Are “Where to start?” / “Point me in the right direction” questions acceptable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226103/are-point-me-in-the-right-direction-questions-acceptable)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this. It loops through all entries and renames the folders

```
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

...

string csv = "csv path";
// Skip the one with the names
string[] items = File.ReadAllLines(csv).Skip(1);
foreach(var item in items)
{
    string oldname = item.Split(';')[0];
    string newname = item.Split(';')[1];
    if(Directory.Exists(oldname) && !Directory.Exists(newname))
        Directory.Move(oldname, newname);
}
```

untested but should work.

Comment: Why split twice? What if the folder name has commas in it? What if the old folder does not exist? What if the new folder already exists? any logging to track the job?

Comment: @luis You're right!  It works until it runs into folders with the same name.  Any suggestion?

Comment: I think your best option is to skip the ones that are duplicates. Assuming the process already renamed them to their new name. I am also assuming that all the new folders are unique in the file.

Comment: Improved the answer.

Comment: @idk - Thanks for that but the thing is, i dont want it to ignore the duplicates because eventually, the "same" folder will be renamed to something else.

Comment: If there's folder A, B and C and A gets renamed to B and later A gets renamed to C which folder should it be? B or C?

Comment: Once A is renamed, it wont get renamed again.  The concern is if A is renamed to B, it should allow it because B later on will get renamed to C.

Comment: When I run the code, A doesn't get renamed to B  because "B" already exist.

Comment: Okay, I`ll fix that

Comment: To understand: There's folder A B and C and A should be renamed to B and B to C?