# How to do a folder Copy from server to local PC

Tags: c#

I have Folders in specified Path Server that has to be copied to specified Path.. How to achieve this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to copy the entire contents of a directory in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744/best-way-to-copy-the-entire-contents-of-a-directory-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

[`File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx)