# How to copy paste using File.Copy C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

```
private void buttonSaveXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFile.Filter = "XML Files|*.xml";
        saveFile.Title = "Save a Xml File";
        saveFile.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\fxo\NewVersion";
        textBoxTargetFolder.Text = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\EdisonFactory\NetOffice";
        saveFile.ShowDialog();
        if (saveFile.FileName != "")
        {
            FileStream fs = (FileStream)saveFile.OpenFile();
            dsVersions.WriteXml(fs);
        }
        string sourceFileFolder = @"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\fxo\NewVersion";
        string destinationFileFolder = @"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\fxo\NewVersion";
        bool overwrite = true;
        File.Copy(sourceFileFolder, destinationFileFolder);
        {
            overwrite = true;
        }
```

I got that much done but i don't know what i am missing. Any help? The button saves XMLs but it also needs to get files from the selected files and copy/paste them where the xml file saves. Also there is an exception on `File.Copy(sourceFileFolder, destinationFileFolder);` How i need to copy is getting the path from one textbox and pasting it from a path into another textbox.

Comment: What do you mean by copy/paste? Do you mean over the clipboard? Because right now you are physically copying the file from one location to another.

Comment: That isn't copy/paste, and what exceptions are you getting?  Please be more clear on what you want to do.  If the code you've provided has nothing to do with the rest of what you want to do, including it just confuses things.

Comment: @PeterRitchie The code with the exception is in the code i posted, it is the 4th to last code there.

Comment: @WolfgangZiegler Yes, i added some more details to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: Don't expect people to download, compile, and run your code to figure out what the exception is.

Comment: @PeterRitchie It doesn't say the exception, just shows that there is one.

Comment: @SovietOnion: I'm pretty sure the runtime tells you what exception it's throwing.  When you debug this, what type of exception is it?  What is the message on the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the individual filenames to File.Copy(), not just the directory.  This appears to be a duplicate question.  See here for answer:

[Best way to copy the entire contents of a directory in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744/best-way-to-copy-the-entire-contents-of-a-directory-in-c-sharp)