# Exclude subdirectories in a directory loop

Tags: c#, .net, subdirectory

In a .NET code, I have a loop that takes all .wav files from D:\Temp and its subdirectories :

```
string[] fileHolder = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\Temp","*.wav", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

I want to exclude all .wav files coming from folders that have "blablabla" in their folder name.

How do do this ?

P.S. This is similar to [Exclude directories that contain sub directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646507/exclude-directories-that-contain-sub-directories/12984087#12984087), but I haven't been able to use successfully the answers of this topic.

Comment: It looks like everything's there in the linked question. What's exactly the problem with applying the answer to what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<string> files = 
   from f in Directory.GetFiles("D:\\Temp", "*.wav", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
   where !Path.GetDirectoryName(f).Contains("blablabla")
   select f;
```

Adding several conditions:

```
var files = from f in Directory.GetFiles("D:\\Temp", "*.wav", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            let directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(f)
            where !directoryName.Contains("blablabla") &&
                  !direcotyName.Contains("foo")
            select f;
```

Another solution: (I think that Path.GetDirectoryName is not fastest possible operation)

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path, string searchPattern,
                                           Func<string, bool> dirSelector)
{
    if (!dirSelector(path))
        yield break;

    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern))
        yield return file;

    foreach (var dir in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        foreach (var file in GetFiles(dir, searchPattern, dirSelector))
            yield return file;
}
```

Usage:

```
Func<string, bool> dirSelector = (d) => !d.Contains("blablabla");
string[] files = GetFiles("D:\\Temp", "*.wav", dirSelector).ToArray();
```

Comment: Is this in C# (with "var" etc.) sorry I don't know much about C#, .net ?

Comment: with this solution, is it also possible to exlcude 3 different words ?
exclude blablabla1, exclude blablabla2, exclude blablabla3 : how to code this?

Comment: thanks lazyberezovsky ! is "var" possible in C# as well?
any idea for multiple exclusions?

Comment: After 3 ifs it's better to use `HashSet<T>.Contains(x)`

Comment: @JosBas `var` is available in C# 3.0 and later

Comment: @abatishchev also it is possible to create `Func<string, bool> fileSelector` and filter files via `.Where(f => fileSelector(f))`

Comment: I use SoundForge scripting language that uses .NET 2 I think... It seems that "var" is not possible (because it doesn't work... any idea)

Comment: @JosBas in this case `var` will be `IEnumerable<string>`. You can apply `ToArray` to query, if you need `string[]`

Answer (score 5):

Try following:

```
string[] fileHolder = Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\temp", "*.wav",
         SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(file => !file.Contains("blabla")).ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 but if the searched text is in the filename and not in the folder name, the file will be excluded

Comment: I think this query will also filter files, which have `blabla` in their names.

Comment: you're both right, thanks.. `Path.GetDirectoryName` or `Regex` would be needed then.. depends on situation

Comment: Is this correct then (if I want to filter foldername only) :       `string[] fileHolder = Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\temp", "*.wav", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(file => !Path.GetDirectoryName(file).Contains("blabla")).ToArray();`

Comment: last question : how can I exlcude files, with foldername containing "blablabla1" or "blablabla2" or "blablabla3"

(I only have 3 names to exclude)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to sort them out manually:

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();
foreach(string filename in Directory.GetFiles("D:\\Temp", "*.wav"))
{
   if (!filename.Contains("blablabla"))
      result.Add(filename);
}
```

Comment: this one is nice as well.
how to choose among all these solutions ? :)