# File access denied changing permissions

Tags: c#, file-io, .net

I'm trying to do an auto-backup program that takes a folder and copies it into another folder. Pretty easy task :

```
File.Copy(Source, Destination);
```

Source is something like `C:\Users\SomeUser\MyDocuments\SavedFiles`
Destination is something like `D:\BackUp`

But when I run my program , I get "Error with access to the path `C:\blabla.....` access is denied.

Is there any type of permission I must change to use the `Copy` method ? I guess so.. I looked a little but I can't find where to change such a thing.
 Any Idea ?

---

UPDATE

[image]

Comment: Have you tried it like File.Copy(Source, Destination, true); // overwrite = true ?

Comment: yes I did sorry I forgot to put it in my question. Also The inaccessible  path is the source.

Comment: Try running visual studio as administrator - does the error go away?

Comment: no it does not. I will post error screen shot in a moment

Comment: Oh my god I just realized I'm using File.Copy when what I want to do is copy an entire folder.... is that my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assume that you might not have permission to access some files and folders on your hard drive.

One solution is to manually run your application with administrator-level permissions, but it is easier to modify the manifest file so that the application automatically seeks admin level when it is run.

You can do this by adding a mainifest file to your project (Add new item...).

Then change the line

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />"
```

to

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />"
```

Obviously, this might not solve your problem if the user who is meant to run the program does not have an administrator-level account.

Comment: I does not work :( Both solution. I tried running as admin before posting here and didn't work either. Also I didn't get the pop up that usually asks for me to accept. On both solutions above..

Comment: That's odd. I read your question comment above and it does state in the MSDN documentation for `File.Copy` that the source argument has to be a file so that could definitely be your problem. In case you haven't found a solution for that, try [the answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744/best-way-to-copy-the-entire-contents-of-a-directory-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Why do you assume that a `File.Copy` operation would (automagically) display a UAC dialog for elevation?

Answer (score 0):

google Shadow Copy service. Thats how the off the shelf packages work.