# copy files from one location to another

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a directory and subdirectories and copy files from on one location to another location. The following code works but it doesn't create a parent directory(10_new) if there are sub directories. I am trying to copy all the contents(including subdirectories) from `"c:\\sourceLoc\\10"` to `"c:\\destLoc\\10_new"` folder. If `"10_new"` doesn't exist then I should create this folder. Please assist.

```
string sourceLoc = "c:\\sourceLoc\\10";
string destLoc = "c:\\destLoc\\10_new";

foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(sourceLoc, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(sourceLoc, destLoc));
    if (Directory.Exists(sourceLoc))
    {
         //Copy all the files
         foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(sourceLoc, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
             File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(sourceLoc, destLoc));
    }
}
```

Comment: Idk if there is an easy peasy library function already but you could recursively check for subfolders and copy each one across.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744/best-way-to-copy-the-entire-contents-of-a-directory-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From looking at your code, you never check for the existence of the parent folders.  You jump to getting all the child folders first.

```
if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\my\dir")) Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\my\dir");
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is how to copy all files in a directory to another directory

This is taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx

```
string sourcePath = "c:\\sourceLoc\\10";
string targetPath = "c:\\destLoc\\10_new";
string fileName = string.Empty;
string destFile = string.Empty;

// To copy all the files in one directory to another directory. 
// Get the files in the source folder. (To recursively iterate through 
// all subfolders under the current directory, see 
// "How to: Iterate Through a Directory Tree.")
// Note: Check for target path was performed previously 
//       in this code example. 
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
{
    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);

    // Copy the files and overwrite destination files if they already exist. 
    foreach (string s in files)
    {
        // Use static Path methods to extract only the file name from the path.
        fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
        destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
        System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Source path does not exist!");
}
```

### [Recursive Directory/Sub-directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-iterate-through-a-directory-tree)

```
public class RecursiveFileSearch
{
    static System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection log = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();

    static void Main()
    {
        // Start with drives if you have to search the entire computer.
        string[] drives = System.Environment.GetLogicalDrives();

        foreach (string dr in drives)
        {
            System.IO.DriveInfo di = new System.IO.DriveInfo(dr);

            // Here we skip the drive if it is not ready to be read. This
            // is not necessarily the appropriate action in all scenarios.
            if (!di.IsReady)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The drive {0} could not be read", di.Name);
                continue;
            }
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo rootDir = di.RootDirectory;
            WalkDirectoryTree(rootDir);
        }

        // Write out all the files that could not be processed.
        Console.WriteLine("Files with restricted access:");
        foreach (string s in log)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void WalkDirectoryTree(System.IO.DirectoryInfo root)
    {
        System.IO.FileInfo[] files = null;
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;

        // First, process all the files directly under this folder
        try
        {
            files = root.GetFiles("*.*");
        }
        // This is thrown if even one of the files requires permissions greater
        // than the application provides.
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {
            // This code just writes out the message and continues to recurse.
            // You may decide to do something different here. For example, you
            // can try to elevate your privileges and access the file again.
            log.Add(e.Message);
        }

        catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        if (files != null)
        {
            foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in files)
            {
                // In this example, we only access the existing FileInfo object. If we
                // want to open, delete or modify the file, then
                // a try-catch block is required here to handle the case
                // where the file has been deleted since the call to TraverseTree().
                Console.WriteLine(fi.FullName);
            }

            // Now find all the subdirectories under this directory.
            subDirs = root.GetDirectories();

            foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs)
            {
                // Resursive call for each subdirectory.
                WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo);
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not copying sub folder images.

Comment: @Billy directly from the above: To recursively iterate through all subfolders under the current directory, see "How to: Iterate Through a Directory Tree.

Answer (score 1):

Before doing File.Copy, check to make sure the folder exists.  If it doesn't create it.
This function will check if a path exists, if it doesnt, it will create it.  If it fails to create it, for what ever reason, it will return false.  Otherwise, true.

```
 Private Function checkDir(ByVal path As String) As Boolean
        Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo(path)
        Dim exist As Boolean = True
        If Not dir.Exists Then
            Try
                dir.Create()
            Catch ex As Exception
                exist = False
            End Try
        End If
        Return exist
    End Function
```

Remember, all .Net languages compile down to the CLR (common language runtime) so it does not matter if this is in VB.Net or C#.  A good way to convert between the two is:  http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: The question is about C#, not VB

Comment: all .Net languages compile down to the CLR and can be easily converted between languages (http://converter.telerik.com/).  Furthermore, this questions isn't language dependent, they are not asking about syntax.

Comment: I agree with jason. Doesnt metter what language you use, you should understand what the logic is beside this code!

Comment: Thanks, I would appreciate an up vote if you agree and the removal of the downvote if you also agree Forte

Comment: @jason, you can only undo a downvote if the answer is edited.

Comment: Although I agree with what you said, the person who asked the question might not understand VB syntax. If you want to show logic then use pseudo code instead of a specific language. (just my opinion)

Comment: Thank you for removing the down vote.  I understand your point but my fear would be that users would refuse to answer questions they knew the answer to in fear of getting down voted because it is in a different syntax.

Answer (score -5):

It is impossible to copy or move files with C# in windows 7.

It will instead create a file of zero bytes.