# how to upload multiple image in asp.net mvc using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to upload multiple images using ASP.NET MVC and Ajax.
Was able to get the code to work and upload 1 image but finding it difficult to upload multiple images in a separate image folder.
Appreciate any help.

please find the HTML code

```
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:20px;">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-md-4" style="margin:0 !important;"><label style="margin-top:5px; margin-left: -15px;">Select image</label></div>
                <div class="col-md-8" style="margin:0 !important;">
                    <span class="control-fileupload ">
                        <input type="file" id="Fimage0" name="ImageUpload" onchange='uploadImage(0)' class="form-control clearMembers">                            
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-md-4" style="margin:0 !important;"><label style="margin-top:5px; margin-left: -15px;">Select image (Spouse)</label></div>
                <div class="col-md-8" style="margin:0 !important;">
                    <span class="control-fileupload ">
                        <input type="file" id="Fimage1" name="ImageUpload" onchange='uploadImage(1)' class="form-control clearMembers">
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

please find the script,

as i have done that get all value in array but i unable to pass the value to ajax append please fine the below ajax.

```
var file; 
        var imagearray = [];
        function uploadImage(Imageid) {
            debugger
            var fileUpload = document.getElementById("Fimage" + Imageid);
            file = fileUpload.files[i];
            imagearray.push(file)    
        }
```

please find the ajax

```
function SaveFamilyInfoDatatoDB() {

            var formData = new FormData();

            formData.append("Name", $('#FName').val());
            //formData.append("file", $('#Fimage')[0].files[0]);
            //formData.append("file", $('#FimageSpouse')[0].files[0]);
            formData.append("file", $('#Fimage0')[0].files[0]);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("SaveAndUpdateFamilyInfo","FamilyInfo")",
                datatype: "JSON",
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                data: 

                    formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (Result) {                   
                    if (Result.type == "success") {                      
                        pushToDocumentArray();                        
                    }
                    else if (Result.type == "NicValidation") {
                        alert("NIC Already Added")
                    } else {
                        alert("11")
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

please find the controller

```
public JsonResult SaveAndUpdateFamilyInfo(Family_Information FamilyInfoMainDeatils, HttpPostedFileBase[] file)
        {
            try
            {
                string imgepath = "Null";
                if (file != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < file.Length; i++)
                    {

                    }
                    //string filename = file.FileName;
                    //imgepath = filename;
                    //string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                    ////  filename = filename + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
                    ////  person.ImagePath = "~/Ima/" + filename;
                    //var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), FamilyInfoMainDeatils.Name + filename);
                    //file.SaveAs(path);
                }

                string FamilyInfoID = Adapter.SaveAndUpdateFamilyInfo_(FamilyInfoMainDeatils, imgepath);

                return Json(new { type = FamilyInfoID });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.ErrorLog(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Refer [How to append whole set of model to formdata and obtain it in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681). Simply change the parameter in your POST method to `HttpPostedFileBase[] ImageUpload` (to match the name of the input), and simply use `var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(0));` (and delete your `uploadImage()` function and the `onchange` in your inputs.

Comment: hi Stephen i have get the error when using (var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(0))) --- formData is not defined - error.

Comment: Well your currently doing `var formData = new FormData();` and not getting that error, so what you claiming is not possible (but it should not be wrapped in parethesis)

Comment: please check the below link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49378686/9520535

Comment: You need to delete that answer - its NOT and answer! And you do not need the `formData.append` lines of code - the `var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(0));` already add all the values of the form controls as explained in the link I gave you (assuming you generate your view correctly which you have not - ALWAYS ALWAYS generate you view with the `@Html.***For(m => m.yourProperty)` methods.

Comment: but most importantly, javascript is case sensitive - you declared a variable named `formdata` (all lower case) which is not the same a `formData` (upper case `D`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DloveJ

you can do one thing, take another folder with the name "**Temporary**". While choosing images through "**File Upload**" input save them to "**Temporary**" folder instead of direct saving to main folder & for preview purpose display it from "**Temporary**" folder. When click on "**Upload image**" button just copy all files from "**Temporary**" folder to your main "**Destination folder**" and make empty "**Temporary**" folder. While copying images from "**Temporary**" folder to "**Destination Folder**" you can perform different operations like change the filename, save image path to DB etc.

**Edit :**

Here, below is the code snippet, please go through it and let me know for any query:

**Step 1:** First create 2 folders. One with the name **Temp** and Second with **[Your Destination Folder Name]**.

**Step 2:** Create user interface.

```
<style>
  img {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-radius: 4px;
      padding: 5px;
      width: 150px;
   }
</style>
 <div class="row" style="margin-top:20px;">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="margin:0 !important;">
            <label style="margin-top:5px; margin-left: -15px;">
                Select image
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8" style="margin:0 !important;">
            <span class="control-fileupload ">
                <input type="file" id="flImage" name="ImageUpload"
                       onchange='uploadTempImage()' class="form-control">
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="imgPreview"></div>
</div>
<div>
<button id="btnSaveImage" onclick="Upload()">Upload Files</button>
</div>
```

**Step 3:** Write a code to make ajax call and to save images.

```
  function UploadTempImage() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $('#flImage')[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/TestImage/SaveToTemp',
        data: formData,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response != null) {
                var my_path = "/temp/" + response;
                var image = '<img src="' + my_path + '" alt="image" style="width:150px">';
                $("#imgPreview").append(image);
            }
        },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        error: function () {
            alert("Whoops something went wrong!");
        }
    });
}

function Upload() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '/TestImage/SaveToMainFolder',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response != null) {
                alert(response);
            }
        },

    });
}
```

**Step 4:** Write a method to handle ajax request into controller.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Save file to Temp folder.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="file"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public JsonResult SaveToTemp(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = "";
            string imgepath = "Null";
            if (file != null)
            {
                filename = file.FileName;
                imgepath = filename;
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                filename = DateTime.Now.Ticks + filename;
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Temp/"), filename);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
            return Json(filename, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is used to move files from Temp folder to Destinatin folder.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public JsonResult SaveToMainFolder()
    {
        //This method has been copied from here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/15140431/5202777 
        string fileName = "";
        string destFile="";
        string sourcePath = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/");
        string targetPath = Server.MapPath("~/[Your Destination Folder Name]/");
        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
        {
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);
            // Copy the files. 
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
                destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
                System.IO.File.Copy(file, destFile, true);
            }
            RemoveFiles();
        }
        return Json("All Files saved Successfully.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Make Temp folder empty once all files are copied to destination folder.
    /// </summary>
    public void RemoveFiles() {
        string sourcePath = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/");
        string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, file)))
            {
                try
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(file);
                }
                catch (System.IO.IOException e)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: hi Krs, please give me some more details because as im send image and data in the ajax, 

formData.append("Wedding_Date", $('#FWeddingDate').val());
            formData.append("Join_Date_Church", $('#FDateofjoin').val());
            formData.append("Baptism_Status", $("input[name='FBaptismradio']:checked").val());
            formData.append("Baptism_Date", $('#FBaptism').val());
            formData.append("file", $('#Fimage')[0].files[0]);