# Console App, trying to move all files from "FolderX" to "FolderX":What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, file, file-io, system.io.directory

```
namespace FileMove2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Which folder would you like to move files from?");
            string sourcePath = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Which folder would you like to move files to?");
            string targetPath = Console.ReadLine();

            MoveDirectory(sourcePath, targetPath);
        }
                static void MoveDirectory(string sourcePath, string targetPath)

            { 
                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
                }

                if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
                {
                    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                    foreach (string f in files)
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Move(f, targetPath);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? What error?

Comment: duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744/best-way-to-copy-the-entire-contents-of-a-directory-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing this instead:

> System.IO.Directory.Move(@"C:\Users\Public\public\test\", @"C:\Users\Public\private");

Where your sourcePath is the first param and targetPath is the second accordingly.

References:
[Microsoft MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [`File.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes two *filenames*, whereas you're providing a filename and a directory.

You can fix your code by creating the appropriate target filename:

```
string targetFile = Path.Combine(targetPath, Path.GetFileName(f));
File.Move(f, targetFile);
```

(As noted by João Pinho, [`Directory.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) may do what you want, but the above explains why you're getting an error, and will help if your real situation is more complicated.)