# Copy everything in a Directory and rename copied Files

Tags: c#, directory, subdirectory

I try to copy everything in a Folder to another, in this case from "sourceFolder" to "targetFolder".

Lets say "sourceFolder" would have two Files in it and 2 subfolder with one additional File:
(i try to show it)

```
//sourceFolder
//├File1.txt
//├File2.txt
//├Subfolder1
//| └File3.txt
//|
//└Subfolder2
//  └File4.txt
```

Now I'm trying to copy all of those files and subfolders from "sourceFolder" to "targetFolder", the subfolders shall be titled the same and on the Files i would to add "a" in front of "Filex.txt"(Exaple: "aFilex.txt")
Thats what im tring to get:

```
//targetFolder
//├aFile1.txt
//├aFile2.txt
//├Subfolder1
//| └aFile3.txt
//|
//└Subfolder2
//  └aFile4.txt
```

current Code:

```
string[] sourceDirectoryFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolderTextbox.Text);
string[] sourceDirectorysubfolders = Directory.GetDirectories(targetFolderTextbox.Text);
string sourcedirectory = sourceFolderTextbox.Text;
string targetdirectory = targetFolderTextbox.Text;

    if (Directory.Exists(sourceDirectorysubfolders[0]))
    {
        foreach (string sourceFilePath in sourceDirectorysubfolders)
        {
                if (!Directory.Exists(sourceFilePath))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(sourceFilePath.Replace(sourcedirectory, targetdirectory));
                    }
            }
    }

    foreach (string sourceFilePath in sourceDirectoryFiles )
    {
        string newsourcefilePath = String.Empty;
        string newfilePath = String.Empty;
        string FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sourceFilePath);
        newsourcefilePath = sourcedirectory + "\\a" + FileName;

        System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFilePath, newfilePath ,true)
    }
```

I hope, I asked clear :)
otherwise I'll answer your questions :)

I'm not good at English or programming so constructive criticism is welcome :)

Comment: Your sample is incomplete. Namely there are no variables defined for surceFolderFolders or surceFolderFiles.

Comment: i hope its better now :)

Comment: So what isn't working? You may also want to rename all variables to write out `source` instead of `surce`.

Comment: currently it does only copy the files in the sourceFolder into the targetFolder and it does create the subfolders. but it does not copy the files / subfolders in  the subfolders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have modified the solution in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744/best-way-to-copy-the-entire-contents-of-a-directory-in-c-sharp) to suit your needs. Hope it helps.

```
void Copy(string sourcePath, string targetPath)
{

    foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(sourcePath, targetPath));

    string newPath;
    foreach (string srcPath in Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        newPath = srcPath.Replace(sourcePath, targetPath);
        newPath = newPath.Insert(newPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1, "a"); //prefixing 'a'
        newPath = newPath +  ".example";
        File.Copy(srcPath, newPath, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: so now im prefixin a but what if i wanna to give it a 2nd extension (.txt.example)
im askin this because i'm a newby im tring to learn / understand