# Cant copy files from one dir to another

Tags: c#, path

I have written a function of copy to copy files from one dir to another but keep getting exception that "The given path's format is not supported" . Here is my function code:

```
private void Copy(string letter)
{
    string sourceDir = (txtPath.ToString());
    string targetDir = letter;
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir))
        File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(file)), true);
}
```

Comment: What is value of letter and txtPath ?

Comment: On which line exactly? Did you debug your code?

Comment: You may use invalid character(s) in your path. Does txtPath contain ":"?

Comment: Why would you ask for help with an error that indicates the file path is invalid, but then not provide the actual file path? If someone were asking _you_ the question, what details would you want to know?

Comment: txtPath contains a path which is being fetched using openfolderdialogue of c# and letter just contains some drive letter where all data needs to be copied.

Comment: i m getting path at runtime so cant really give paths.

Comment: letter has probably a wrong value.

Comment: there are no mediums, but _letter just contains some drive letter where all data needs to be copied_ sounds like you provide 'D' instead of 'D:\\' in `letter` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refer to the content of a TextBox you use the `TextBox.Text` property

```
private void Copy(string letter)
{
    string sourceDir = txtPath.Text.Trim();
    string targetDir = letter;

    // Check if source and target exists....
    if(Directory.Exists(sourceDir) && Directory.Exists(targetDir))
    {
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir))
            File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(file)), true);
    }
    else
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Source=" + sourceDir + " or Target: " + targetDir + " doesn't exist"): 
    }
}
```

Calling the `ToString()` method directly on the instance of the TextBox returns the name of the class followed by the text property (Something like **"System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text:content of the textbox"**) and obviously this is not a valid path

It is not clear from your comments what is the content of the variable letter. So you should also be sure that the variable `targetDir` points to an actual valid path.
(A single drive letter **C D or E** are not valid paths)

Comment: ty v much .. I forgot some basic thing because of exhaustion . But this function is only copying files in that dir not folders ... Any help?

Comment: If you want to copy also the content of the subfolders you need a recursive call. Probably there are a lot of examples around. The first one found is this http://www.rhyous.com/2011/07/25/how-to-copy-a-directory-recursively-in-cshar/ and this could be considered a classic given the upvotes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744/best-way-to-copy-the-entire-contents-of-a-directory-in-c-sharp