# Copy directory with all files and folders

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to copy one directory to another path.
I found this method, but it does not copy the directory, only the sub-directories and files inside it:

```
string sourcedirectory = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%AppData%\\Program");

foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(sourcedirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(sourcedirectory, folderDialog.SelectedPath));
}
foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(sourcedirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(sourcedirectory, folderDialog.SelectedPath), true);
}
```

How I can get the "Program" folder in output with all files and sub-folders?

Comment: What do you mean "it does not copy the directory"? It obviously copies the directory itself -- it wouldn't be able to copy the subdirectories and files if the top-level directory wasn't present in the output. Do you mean it doesn't copy the files in the top-level directory? It sure seems like it would, just scanning through the code. (Personally, I prefer a recursive solution, rather than relying on `string.Replace()` or other path manipulation, but the code here looks reasonable enough).

Comment: @PeterDuniho The directory "Program" is not created but the files and folders inside it are copied to destination. I need to get the "Program" directory in output.

Comment: I believe it is duplicated question.
Look at the MSDN solution of this question (I think it is last) - it should copy all, including the directory itself.

[Copy directory c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744/best-way-to-copy-the-entire-contents-of-a-directory-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @DotNet: it should work fine, if you set `newPath` so that it's actually the output directory named `Program` you want the output to go to. Worst-case scenario, you just add `newPath = Path.Combine(newPath, Path.GetFileName(sourcedirectory))` to the code just before the first `foreach`.

Comment: @ZivWeissman This is not a duplicate question. I'm using the same method that is in one of the answers in the question you referred.

Comment: @PeterDuniho This is very strange. I do not get the "Program" folder as output, just the folders and files inside it. You even tested?

Comment: @DotNet: sorry, I should re-word the second suggestion: it's not `newPath` that needs changing, but rather `folderDialog.SelectedPath`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Combining the paths worked, now I'm getting the "Program" folder as output with all their proper files and folders inside. Please add an answer and I will mark this as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: done...sorry for the false start. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you adjust the output path before you start copying, it should work:

```
string sourcedirectory = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%AppData%\\Program");

folderDialog.SelectedPath = Path.Combine(folderDialog.SelectedPath,
    Path.GetFileName(sourcedirectory));

foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(sourcedirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(sourcedirectory, folderDialog.SelectedPath));
}
foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(sourcedirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(sourcedirectory, folderDialog.SelectedPath), true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function to do it:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.CopyAll(new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Original"), new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Copy"));
    }
    private void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo oOriginal, DirectoryInfo oFinal)
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo oFolder in oOriginal.GetDirectories())
            this.CopyAll(oFolder, oFinal.CreateSubdirectory(oFolder.Name));

        foreach (FileInfo oFile in oOriginal.GetFiles())
            oFile.CopyTo(oFinal.FullName + @"\" + oFile.Name, true);
    }
```