# Copy external folder when publish project

Tags: c#, publish, pubxml

I have excluded build folder from project.
But when publish the project, I would like to copy the folder and its subfolders content to the root of the project. How can I include that into publish pubxml file?

Answer (score 0):

By using relative paths

```
private String newPath(Int32 noOfLevels, String SourcePath) 
{

   String path = "";
   for(int i=0; i< noOfLevels; i++) {
     path+= "..\";
   }
   path += SourcePath;
   return path;
}
```

and

```
//Now Create all of the directories
foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath, "*", 
    SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));

//Copy all the files & Replaces any files with the same name
foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*", 
    SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath), true);
```

found at [Copy the entire contents of a directory in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744/best-way-to-copy-the-entire-contents-of-a-directory-in-c-sharp)

It would be a duplicate question if not for the use of relative paths.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to do that when someone publish project, so I wan't to include code in pubxml file and not in cs.