# C# Copy list of files to another location with relative paths

Tags: c#, windows, copy, filesystems, relative-path

I have a program that lists a number of files from a selected directory and in all the subdirectories. 
A list is created that lists specific selected files with relative paths:

> \blender-2.77-windows64\OpenColorIO.dll
>   \blender-2.77-windows64\pthreadVC2.dll

Now I want to copy all the files to a target directory and create all the directories and subdirectories of the relative paths aswell. I have been looking around a little bit but I couldn't find anything really. Is there a specific method for this or can you do a smart loop? Please help me!

Comment: You can use xcopy windows utility, I think it is the best option.

Comment: Similar Question [StackoverFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744/best-way-to-copy-the-entire-contents-of-a-directory-in-c-sharp)