# C# Copy entire Removeable Disk to shared folder

Tags: c#, copy, filesystems, directory

In my app i need to copy entire XDCam Disks (prof. Broadcast Record Disk) to our fileserver. But following function only seems to wirk if the source drive is not a root directory.

Not working

```
    FileSystem.CopyDirectory("E:\\", serverPath + this.targtetDirectory + "\\", UIOption.AllDialogs);
```

Working

```
FileSystem.CopyDirectory("E:\\Clip\\", serverPath + this.targtetDirectory + "\\", UIOption.AllDialogs);
```

How can i copy the entire disk to my target directory?

Comment: for all files and directories copy files, and do the filesyste.copydirectory for directories?

Comment: What is it doing when it is "not working"? Is there an error? Is it doing absolutely nothing at all and continuing with whatever code is next?

Comment: This may be a permissions issue - do you **need** to be able to copy from the root?

Comment: Do you expect all folders to be copied - that method is not recursive. If so [Best way to copy the entire contents of a directory in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744/best-way-to-copy-the-entire-contents-of-a-directory-in-c-sharp)

Comment: According to the Docs - attempting to copy the root directory will cause an IOException - so you will probably have to copy all folders from the root separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it in the past:

```
void CopyAppFiles(string SourcePath, string )
{
    foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));
    }

    foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath), true);
    }
}
```

With progress you could do something like

```
void CopyAppFiles(string SourcePath, string )
{
    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

    int totalOperations = dirs.length + files.length;

    for(int i = 0; i < dirs.length; i++)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirs[i].Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));

        ReportProgress(i, totalOperations);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        File.Copy(files[i], files[i].Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath), true);

        ReportProgress(i + dirs.length, totalOperations);
    }
}

void ReportProgress(int currentOperation, int totalOperations)
{
    //TODO
}
```

works best with small files

Comment: That works fine. Only thing is that i don't have progress bar anymore. So that will be the next thing to implement. I need a progressbar because older XDCam Drives are USB 2.0 only and the disk can contain up to 50GB. So i need something to monitor the copy process. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of targeting the root directory, try getting all the subdirectories of the root and copy them individually:

```
string destinationDir = serverPath + this.targetDirectory + @"\";
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\", "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    File.Copy(file, destinationDir + file.Substring(targetDirectory.Length));
}
```

Comment: File.Copy(file, destinationDir + file.Substring(targetDirectory.Length));This causes ArgumentOutOfRange Exception :(