# Copy all files in subfolders to another folder using c# with subfolder name

Tags: c#

My source path is `C:\images\` in which I have hundreds of folders called Album-1, Album-2 etc. I create a target path `F:\AllPics`.  And then I want to move all the files inside my albums to the target path, so that I get all the images in one folder with subfolder names like album-1_img1,album2-img2.  How can I do this ?

Comment: Did you even try anything? what have you done so far? SO isn't a code writing machine.

Comment: What did you try so far ? SO is not a coding service take a look here :http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This has been asked so many times its ridiculous

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to copy the entire contents of a directory in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744/best-way-to-copy-the-entire-contents-of-a-directory-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
namespace MassFileMoverConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        string _sourcePath;
        string _targetPath;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program massMover = new Program();
            massMover.MoveThemAll();
        }

        void MoveThemAll()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter source path : ");
            _sourcePath  = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter target path : ");
            _targetPath = Console.ReadLine();

            var subFolderNamesTargetPath = Directory.GetDirectories(_sourcePath);
            foreach(var subFolderName in subFolderNamesTargetPath)
            {
                var subFolder = new DirectoryInfo(subFolderName);
                var subFolderFiles = subFolder.GetFiles();
                foreach(var subFolderFile in subFolderFiles)
                {
                    var fileNewName = subFolder.Name + "_" + subFolderFile.Name;
                    subFolderFile.CopyTo(Path.Combine(_targetPath, fileNewName));
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @lightcoder Happy to hear that, you're welcome! I think you got some downvotes on this question since it doesn't contain any visible code/research effort, which is generally frowned upon in SO. To avoid this in future questions it's better to look through tutorials, try to write code, and post a question if/when you get stuck. Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the File & Directory classes.
You can iterate through the files in a directory similar to this (may need tweeks)
There are options to include directories etc.

```
// Process the list of files found in the directory.
string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
foreach(string fileName in fileEntries)
    ProcessFile(fileName);

// Recurse into subdirectories of this directory.
string [] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory);
foreach(string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
    ProcessDirectory(subdirectory);
```

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles()` takes a path at the very least and then a search pattern. You have also missed `"` as well.