# Filter Directory structure by Created date and then Copy using c#

Tags: c#, filter, copy, directory-structure

I want to Filter files in an entire directory structure by created date property and then copy preserving this new filtered directory structure to the destination using c#.

I Have found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/690980), but it does not filter.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class CopyDir
{
  public static void Copy(string sourceDirectory, string targetDirectory)
  {
    DirectoryInfo diSource = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectory);
    DirectoryInfo diTarget = new DirectoryInfo(targetDirectory);

    CopyAll(diSource, diTarget);
  }

public static void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);

    // Copy each file into the new directory.
    foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"Copying {0}\{1}", target.FullName, fi.Name);
        fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, fi.Name), true);
    }

    // Copy each subdirectory using recursion.
    foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceSubDir in source.GetDirectories())
    {
        DirectoryInfo nextTargetSubDir =
            target.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceSubDir.Name);
        CopyAll(diSourceSubDir, nextTargetSubDir);
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    string sourceDirectory = @"c:\sourceDirectory";
    string targetDirectory = @"c:\targetDirectory";

    Copy(sourceDirectory, targetDirectory);
}

// Output will vary based on the contents of the source directory.
```

}

Comment: What you want to filter exactly? By file-type, or creation date, oder maybe size?

Comment: @TripleEEE by creation date only

Comment: show us your code and we may be able to help

Comment: @SimonPrice i have edit my post to include the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after you told us you want to "filter" by the creation date you could do something like:

```
//If date is newer than 1 week
if(fi.CreationTime >= DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromDays(7))
   fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, fi.Name), true);
```