# Program that copies only certain files and folders C#

Tags: c#, copy, backup

```
private void btn_Backup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<DirectoryInfo> SourceDir = this.lbox_Sources.Items.Cast<DirectoryInfo>().ToList();
        List<DirectoryInfo> TargetDir = this.lbox_Targets.Items.Cast<DirectoryInfo>().ToList();


        foreach (DirectoryInfo sourcedir in SourceDir)
        {
            foreach (DirectoryInfo targetdir in TargetDir)
            {
                string dateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy_H.mm.ss");

                if (this.checkbox_zipfiles.Checked == true)
                {
                    System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(sourcedir.FullName, targetdir.FullName + @"\BACKUP_" + sourcedir.Name + @"_" + dateString + @".zip");

                    LogBackup();
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var file in sourcedir.GetFiles()
                        .Where(f => !extensionsToSkip.Contains(f.Extension) && !filesToSkip.Contains(f.FullName)).ToList())
                    {
                        file.CopyTo(targetdir.FullName + @"\" + file.Name, true);
                        LogBackup();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

So far I have this code that only works on files, how do I make it work for folders and subfolders and files in folders?

Comment: Write a recursive function for copy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy the entire contents of a directory in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744/copy-the-entire-contents-of-a-directory-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a Copy recursive function like this (Pseudo code)

```
public void CopyData(string sourceDirectoryPath, string desDirectoryPath)
{
    foreach File in sourceDirectoryPath
    {
        copy to desDirectoryPath
    }

    foreach currentDirectory in sourceDirectoryPath
    {
        // recursive function
        CopyData( currentDirectory,  correspondingdesDirectoryPath)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test code but it would look something like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace divideSquare
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void btn_Backup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<DirectoryInfo> SourceDir = this.lbox_Sources.Items.Cast<DirectoryInfo>().ToList();
            List<DirectoryInfo> TargetDir = this.lbox_Targets.Items.Cast<DirectoryInfo>().ToList();

            for(int i = 0; i < SourceDir.Count(); i++)
            {
                DirectoryInfo sourcedir = SourceDir[i];
                DirectoryInfo targetdir = TargetDir[i];
                RecursiveZip(sourcedir, targetdir);
            }
        }
        private void RecursiveZip(DirectoryInfo sourcedir, DirectoryInfo targetdir)
        {
                string dateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy_H.mm.ss");

                if (this.checkbox_zipfiles.Checked == true)
                {
                    System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(sourcedir, targetdir.FullName + @"\BACKUP_" + sourcedir.Name + @"_" + dateString + @".zip");

                    LogBackup();
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var file in sourcedir.GetFiles()
                        .Where(f => !extensionsToSkip.Contains(f.Extension) && !filesToSkip.Contains(f.FullName)).ToList())
                    {
                        file.CopyTo(targetdir.FullName + @"\" + file.Name, true);
                        LogBackup();
                    }
                    foreach(DirectoryInfo folder in sourcedir.GetDirectories())
                    {
                        RecursiveZip(folder, new DirectoryInfo(targetdir.FullName + "\\" + folder.Name));
                    }
                }
        }

}
```